# Container doesn't register itself in eureka service

Tags: java, spring, docker, netflix-eureka

I am using `Docker Toolbox` and the `Oracle VM` it comes with.

The automatic registration works fine outside `docker`. 
When I run them as a `container` I can view both of them using `192.168.99.100:8761` and `192.168.99.100:8080`in the `VM`s browser. It's just the registration of the `client` at the `eureka-service` which is not working.

I have also tried to link them using `network` and when I `inspect` the `network` it shows me that both container are in the `network`. But the client still does not register itself in the `eureka-service`.

**EUREKA-SERVICE**

`application.yml:`

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://192.168.99.100:8761/
```

`bootstrap.yml:`

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-service
```

**MICROSERVICE (CLIENT)**

`application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop
spring.datasource.username=shop
spring.datasource.password=shop
server.port=8080
```

`application.yml`

```
server:
  port: 8080
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://192.168.99.100:8761/
                     //IP of the VM:EUREKA PORT
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
spring:
    jpa:
        database: MYSQL
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: validate

    datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/shop
        username: shop
        password: shop
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 1):

Set log level to info, and pls check the app logs while you start your app, pay attention to these logs:

```
2018-03-26 17:00:42.618  INFO [,] [10460] [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Disable delta property : false
2018-03-26 17:00:42.618  INFO [,] [10460] [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Single vip registry refresh property : null
2018-03-26 17:00:42.619  INFO [,] [10460] [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Force full registry fetch : false
2018-03-26 17:00:42.619  INFO [,] [10460] [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Application is null : false
2018-03-26 17:00:42.619  INFO [,] [10460] [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Registered Applications size is zero : true
2018-03-26 17:00:42.619  INFO [,] [10460] [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Application version is -1: true
2018-03-26 17:00:42.619  INFO [,] [10460] [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2018-03-26 17:00:42.785  INFO [,] [10460] [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: The response status is 200
2018-03-26 17:00:42.786  INFO [,] [10460] [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 5
2018-03-26 17:00:42.788  INFO [,] [10460] [main] com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator: InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
2018-03-26 17:00:42.792  INFO [,] [10460] [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1522054842792 with initial instances count: 1
2018-03-26 17:00:42.822  INFO [,] [10460] [main] org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry: Registering application service-testServerConsumer with eureka with status UP
2018-03-26 17:00:42.823  INFO [,] [10460] [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1522054842823, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2018-03-26 17:00:42.826  INFO [,] [10460] [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: DiscoveryClient_SERVICE-TESTSERVERCONSUMER/10.234.97.21:service-testServerConsumer:8101: registering service...
2018-03-26 17:00:42.881  INFO [,] [10460] [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: DiscoveryClient_SERVICE-TESTSERVERCONSUMER/10.234.97.21:service-testServerConsumer:8101 - registration status: 204
```

Check if registration status is 204.

If not found, pls check the network issue and if eureka is accessible if you observe this:

```
2018-03-26 17:03:50.048  WARN [,] [1648] [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient: Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2018-03-26 17:03:50.048  WARN [,] [1648] [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient: DiscoveryClient_SERVICE-TESTSERVERCONSUMER/10.234.97.21:service-testServerConsumer:8101 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:798) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:104) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$1.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:88) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_144]

2018-03-26 17:03:50.049  WARN [,] [1648] [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator: There was a problem with the instance info replicator

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:798) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:104) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$1.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:88) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_144]
```

To check if eureka is accessible, if your eureka is started within spring cloud, pls execute `curl http://192.168.99.100:8761/eureka/apps` to see if you can get the list of servers.